# AngularJS UI-router - how to distinguish between part of url and url parametr?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have these states defined:

1)
url: "/Home/:organization"

2)
url: "/Home/administration"

In the browser, if I go to "/Home/" or to "/Home/5", then it is OK, state 1) is recognized.
But if I go to "/Home/administration", then it is BAD, not state 2) is recognized as I expected, but again state 1) with string "administration" as parametr for organization.

How to handle this?

Comment: instead of handling it, I would think my design of URLs is flawed and should be changed instead..

Comment: I think you should change url2: => /administration  instead of handling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) url: "/Home/administration" 
2) url: "/Home/:organization"`

.state('administration',{
    url : '/Home/administration',
    templateUrl : 'administration.html'
})
.state('organization',{
    url : '/Home/:organization',
    templateUrl : 'organization.html'
})
```

change the orders of your routes, put administration routes before `stateParamas` routes. when we Enter some URL, It  search for the matching url in our config  and return matching url's html. when you put your `stateparams` state before default state. it will accept your administration as a value of organization `stateParams`. hope this will help you.